pywintypes.com_error when using getCellValue in SAP GUI Scripting with Python
I'm working on a Python script that interacts with SAP GUI using the win32com.client module. My goal is to retrieve a specific cell value from a table within SAP. However, I'm encountering an error when I attempt to use the getCellValue method. Below is the traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aaaa\Desktop\test.py", line 69, in <module>
    value = shell.getCellValue(1, "Status do sistema")
  File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 2, in getCellValue
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'SAP Frontend Server', '', None, 0, -2147024809), None)

Here is the relevant part of my code:
My code
id = 'wnd[0]/usr/cntlCUSTOM/shellcont/shell/shellcont/shell'
shell = sap.session.findById(id)

value = shell.getCellValue(1, "Status do sistema")

print(value)

Based on the SAP GUI Scripting API documentation, the getCellValue method has the following signature in VBScript:
Public Function GetCellValue( _
   ByVal Row As Long, _
   ByVal Column As String _
) As String

What I've Tried

Verification: Ensured that SAP GUI scripting is enabled on my system.
ID Path: Double-checked the ID path
(wnd[0]/usr/cntlCUSTOM/shellcont/shell/shellcont/shell) to ensure it
correctly points to the table I want to interact with.

Column Reference: Tried using both the column name ("Status do
sistema") and the column index (e.g., 0, 1) to retrieve the value.

Testing Different Parameters: I also experimented with different row
indices and column names to see if the issue was specific to certain
cells.


I expected the getCellValue method to return the value from the specified cell in the table, which I would then print to the console.

Python Version: 3.11.8

SAP GUI Version: (SAP GUI version 770)

win32com.client Version: 306

Operating System: Windows 10


Question
What could be causing this pywintypes.com_error when I try to use getCellValue? Is there something wrong with how I am referencing the column, or might there be an issue with the SAP GUI setup? I would appreciate any guidance on how to correctly retrieve the cell value.

GetCellValue(Row As Long, Column As String) As String: Column should be the technical ID, not the title. These IDs can be retrieved via the ColumnOrder property (GuiCollection object). I have updated this answer accordingly.

Thank you, I entered the column id obtained through "ColumnOrder" and it worked =)

This error may happen for any misuse of SAP GUI Scripting and is not specific to Python or win32com.client module.
For instance, in your case, you are specifying incorrectly the second parameter of GetCellValue which must be the column name, not the column title:
value = shell.getCellValue(1, "Status do sistema")

How to get the column names is detailed in this answer.
